# How to make a sync database query with Mysql and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to make a SELECT query in my database using mysql nodejs module. The problem is that `connection.query` function is an asyncronous function so I put it inside a promise like this:

```
function execQuery(query, fields){
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, fields, (err, results) => {
            connection.end();
            if (err){
                return reject(err);
            }else{
                return resolve(results);
            }
        }
    )
```

This function is called by another function:

```
function getPasswordFromUser(username){
    query = 'SELECT password FROM User WHERE username=?'
    parameters = [username]

    execQuery(query, parameters)
        .then(result => {
            if (result !== undefined && result.length === 1){
                console.log('here1')
                return result
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    console.log('here2')
}
```

the problem is that despite I return a promise and use `then`, in my console I receive:

```sh
here2
here1
```

So my query keeps running in asynchronous mode and I can't get the result.

What is the best way to do this using promise?

Comment: How your doing it is correct, what I would do extra is `return execQuery(..` so that anyone calling `getPasswordFromUser(` can attach to the promise chain too.

Comment: A promise is still asynchronous, using promises doesn't make anything synchronous. If you want `here2` to occur later, you will need to put it in the `then` callback as well. `getPasswordFromUser` will need to return a promise as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you are not returning the promise, and that's it.

do:
`return execQuery(query, parameters)`

And you use it like a simple promise.

```
getPasswordFromUser('userid')
.then((result)=>{
  ..do stuff..
});
```

or if you are using `async-await` use a async function and await the  `getPasswordFromUser` function. For example for an express route.

```
app.post('/getPassword', async (req,res) =>{
    const userID = req.body.userID;
    const password = await getPasswordFromUser(userID);
    res.send(password);
});
```

**Note:** The route is a joke, I hope you are not storing password in plain text, and if you want to match the password(like login) you should do something like: `select count(*) from user where username=username and password=hash(password);` or maybe you are matching the password using `bcrypt` or something.

Comment: So I can't use the result outside a '.then' statement? What if I want to use this result in another function? Do I have to call the function inside the '.then'? This could be a monstrous code if I need to process this variable many times.

Comment: This is how asynchronous functions work, if you want to use even one async function you need to structure all the code asynchronously. But that's why there is `async-await`. It gives you the impression that this is synchronous but behind the scenes it makes the function asynchronous. If you want to process the variable many times simply store it in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing `here2` first because it's not inside the `then`.  The program continues to execute after it starts the `execQuery` function.

You can return a promise:

```
function getPasswordFromUser(username){
    query = 'SELECT password FROM User WHERE username=?'
    parameters = [username]

    return execQuery(query, parameters)
        .then(result => {
            if (result !== undefined && result.length === 1){
                console.log('here1')
                return result
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Then add `.then(result => { ... })` to the function call to get the result.

Comment: I tried this solution but now in the function that calls getPasswordFromUser() I'm receiving a Promise<pending>. I want to return only the result of query

Comment: The only way to get that value is to add a `.then(result => { ... })` to the `getPasswordFromUser` function call.  That's just how promises/async works.